# putting whole application in landscape mode in manifest

Tags: android

The line `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in each activity in manifest file will put that activity in landscape.
Is there any way to put whole application in landscape in manifest? I put it in application field but didnt work.
I have an app which will only use landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You might somehow embed it into the code before you launch your activities, but overall, the activities specification must have that setting. Look at the specification [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).

Comment: Yes. I was wondering why I can do android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" for whole application but not the screenOrientation. I think android people they should add this specification! it is needed!